# Problem with saving custom object into NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a custom object class with the following .m:

```
@implementation FolderObject

    @synthesize folderTitle, folderContents; //title is NSString, contents is array

    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
        [coder encodeObject:foldersContents forKey:@"foldersContents"];
        [coder encodeObject:folderTitle forKey:@"folderTitle"];

    }
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
        self = [[FolderObject alloc] init];
        if (self != nil)
        {
            foldersContents = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"foldersContents"];
            folderTitle = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"folderTitle"]; 
        }   
        return self;
    }
    @end
```

Here is how I use the folder (in some other class):

```
FolderObject *newFolder=[FolderObject alloc];
        newFolder.folderTitle=[textView text];
        newFolder.folderContents=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        [folders addObject:newFolder];
```

Here is how I save and retrieve the custom object from NSUserDefaults:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:folders] forKey:@"folders"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArrayFolders = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"folders"];
    if (dataRepresentingSavedArrayFolders != nil)
    {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArrayFolders];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil) {
            folders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        }
        else {
            folders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }

    else folders=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And finally here is where the issue is:

```
        FolderObject *newFolder=[folders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [folderTitleLabel setText:newFolder.folderTitle];
```

On the second line, I get an error during runtime, but only after I exit the app and come back. When I add objects to the folders array and call the above, no problems. But if I exit the app and come back, then problems:

```
 -[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b9e400
2011-09-02 08:09:24.290 MyApp[43504:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b9e400'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of `initWithCoder:` for your `FolderObject` you are not properly retaining the values which will result in your crash. Make sure you use the property like this.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        //dot notation (self.) will properly retain or copy your string
        //as long as it is declared as retain or copy (I recommend copy)
        self.foldersContents = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"foldersContents"];
        self.folderTitle = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"folderTitle"]; 
    }   
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I actually just tried this before you answered, and that still didn't solve the problem. Now I'm just getting a general crash but its not telling me where. Anywhere else I should use self?

Comment: Is your @property declared with `retain` or `copy`? Everything else appears to be correct.

Comment: It's declared nonatomic, retain. The foldersContent is an NSMutableArray, if that makes any difference

Comment: That could cause another problem try, `self.folderContents = [[coder ..] mutableCopy] autorelease];` and see if the helps you. While that needs to be done, somewhere else an array is either accidentally being set to your folderTitle or folderTitle is being over released. Make sure the only place you call `[folderTitle release];` is in dealloc.

Comment: @mohabitar - I just realized that you are creating a memory leak where you set `self = [[FolderObject alloc] init];`. It should just be `self = [super init];`. Edit: now that I wrote this comment I see deanWombourne has mentioned this below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your `initWithCoder:` method:

```
        foldersContents = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"foldersContents"];
        folderTitle = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"folderTitle"];
```

The values returned by `decodeObjectForKey:` are not retained for you, and as you are assigning them to ivars directly instead of via the (presumably) `retain`-declared properties, they are not being retained there either. So they get auto-released the next time the autorelease pool is drained. By the time you get around to trying to use it, it just so happens that the memory location formerly used for the title is now occupied by an `__NSArrayM` object; were things to work out slightly differently, you'd get a more straightforward EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash.

Comment: @mohabitar: Either retain the returned objects explicitly, or use property notation (e.g. `self.folderTitle`) for the assignment to properties declared `retain` or `copy`. You might also try using NSZombieEnabled during this debugging, which will make errors due to accessing a released object more deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe is right about needing to `retain` the objects but why are you using

```
self = [[FolderObject alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
self = [super init];
```

Your code will leak an chunk of memory each time it's called?

I don't know if it's causing your crash (I suspect not) but it's certainly interesting.